# What is the difference between a copper electromagnet ( that is, an electromagnet with a copper core) and regular copper in terms of magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If I bring a magnet close to a copper bar, there will be no attractive or repulsive force. Similarly, if I bring a magnet close to a copper electromagnet, still there is no attractive or repulsive force.

So can't we say that the magnetism of regular copper and a copper electromagnet the same ?

If no, then why? What difference is there between regular copper and a copper electromagnet? How does copper get changed if electricity passes through it?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the magnetism *of the copper* in the regular copper and the copper electromagnet are the same.

The magnetic force of a copper electromagnet comes not from the copper, but *from the electrons flowing through the copper*.  Currents produce magnetic forces.  That's why it's called an *electro*magnet, you need electricity to produce a magnetic force.

Comment: Re, "why do we call a copper electromagnet an electroMAGNET...?" because it _acts_ like a magnet when current flows through it.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the answer, but I just have one confusion. You said," the magnetism of the copper in the regular copper and the copper electromagnet are the same." that is, no magnetism. Then why do we call a copper electromagnet an electroMAGNET if it doesn't have any magnetic property?

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan, a copper electromagnet *does* have magnetic properties.  The magnetism is not coming from the copper though, it's coming from the electricity flowing through the copper.  The copper itself does not have its magnetic properties changed when it is used as an electromagnet.

Comment: @Joshua But how exactly does the current induce magnetism? Could u please provide me with some links? Thanks!

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan current produces magnetism because that's how the universe works.  The answer linked hereafter provides an explanation in the context of special relativity, but the simple answer is "because it does." https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-moving-charge-produce-a-magnetic-field-around-it

Answer (score 1):

> If I bring a magnet close to a copper bar, there will be no attractive or repulsive force.

This assertion it’s not true, because all the materials have magnetic properties. The principal phenomenon present in copper is the so-called **diamagnetism** (see [Diamagnetism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism)) and consists of a macroscopic small repulsion. This magnetic property is present in every material, but it’s not always visible because of preponderance of other magnetic phenomena like paramagnetism, ferromagnetism et alia.